# Converting any PHP function toString() like in JS

Tags: javascript, php, strings, functional-programming, converting

In JavaScript, any function is basically an object on which you can call (`function(){}).toString()` to get it's underlying code as a string.

I'm working on a function aimed to do the job in PHP. The intended goal is to convert code from PHP into other languages, such as JavaScript.

It looks like this so far:

```
function fn_to_string($fn, $strip_comments = true) {

    static $contents_cache = array();
    static $nl = "\r\n"; # change this to how you want

    if(!is_callable($fn)) return ''; # it should be a function
    if(!class_exists('ReflectionFunction')) return ''; # PHP 5.1 I think

    # get function info
    $rfn = new ReflectionFunction($fn);
    $file = $rfn->getFileName();
    $start = $rfn->getStartLine();
    $end = $rfn->getEndLine();

    if(!is_readable($file)) return ''; # file should be readable

    # cache file contents for subsequent reads (in case we use multiple fns defined in the same file)
    $md5 = md5($file);
    if(!isset($contents_cache[$md5]))
        $contents_cache[$md5] = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    if(empty($contents_cache[$md5])) return ''; # there should be stuff in the file
    $file = $contents_cache[$md5];

    # get function code and tokens
    $code = "<?php ". implode($nl, array_slice($file, $start-1, ($end+1)-$start));
    $tokens = token_get_all( $code);

    # now let's parse the code;
    $code = '';
    $function_count = 0;
    $ignore_input = false; # we use this to get rid of "use" or function name
    $got_header = false;
    $in_function = false;
    $braces_level = 0;
    foreach($tokens as $token){

        # get the token name or string
        if(is_string($token)){
            $token_name = $token;
        }elseif(is_array($token) && isset($token[0]) ){
            $token_name = token_name($token[0]);
            $token = isset($token[1]) ? $token[1] : "";
        }else{
            continue;
        }

        # strip comments
        if( 1
            && $strip_comments 
            && ($token_name == "T_COMMENT" || $token_name == "T_DOC_COMMENT" || $token_name == "T_ML_COMMENT")
        ){
            # but put back the new line
            if(substr($token,-1) == "\n")
                $code.=$nl;
            continue;
        }

        # let's decide what to do with it now
        if($in_function){

            # nesting level
            if($token_name == "{"){
                $braces_level++;

                # done ignoring `use`
                $ignore_input = false;
            }

            # append
            if( 1 
                && $function_count==1
                && ( 0
                    # skip function names
                    || ( $ignore_input && $token_name == "(" && !$got_header && (!($ignore_input=false)) ) 

                    # skip function () use (...) in closures functions
                    || ( $braces_level == 0 && !$got_header && $token_name == ")" && ($ignore_input=true) && ($got_header=true) )

                    # this fall-through is intentional
                    || !$ignore_input 
                )
            ) {
                $code .= $token;
            }

            # ending "}"
            if($token_name == "}"){
                $braces_level--;

                # done collecting the function
                if($braces_level == 0)
                    $in_function = false;
            }

        }elseif($token_name == "T_FUNCTION"){
            $function_count++;
            $in_function = true;
            $ignore_input = true;
            $braces_level = 0;
            $code.=$token;

            # we can't detect this properly so bail out
            if($function_count>1){
                $code = '';
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $code;
}
```

The function uses the [ReflectionFunction](http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) class to determine where the passed function was declared, and [`token_get_all()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) to process the different parts of the declaration.

This works as intended:

1. Handles function names passed as strings
2. Handles variable functions
3. Handles closures and lambdas
4. Can even handle itself
5. Can strip out comments

However,

1. It relies on the undocumented-yet class, `ReflectionFunction`
2. Fails if it can't read its own source files
3. Fails if there are multiple functions declared on the same line(s) where the passed function was declared:

   ```
   function a(){} function b(){} fn_to_string('a'); // fails
   ```
4. Cannot determine scope or context so it strips out function names and the `use` keyword to avoid future problems

I'm trying to determine if something like this is ready for the real world, so my questions are:

1. Are there any reasons for which using this approach may not be a good idea?
2. Are there any foreseeable performance issues?
3. Are there any better alternatives?
4. Are there any overlooked cases which the function doesn't cover?
5. Are there server settings in which a script may not be able to read itself

   ```
   is_readable(__FILE__)===false
   ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It relies on the undocumented-yet class, ReflectionFunction

`ReflectionFunction` is [not undocumented](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php).

> Fails if it can't read its own source files

Seems unavoidable.

> Fails if there are multiple functions declared on the same line(s) where the passed function was declared

Why not just return everything in the range of lines `ReflectionFunction` gives us, since that's as accurate as it can get? Which leads to the inevitable question, what is the use case for all of this?

> Cannot determine scope or context so it strips out function names and the `use` keyword to avoid future problems

What problems? If you explained how you planned to use this, that might make more sense (context!).

> Are there any reasons for which using this approach may not be a good idea?

Can you first explain what reasons you are doing this for in the first place?

> Are there any foreseeable performance issues?

1. Parsing the function (`token_get_all`) seems unnecessary when all you want to do is get the function's source.
2. Using the MD5 hash of the filename as a cache key seems unnecessary, why not just use the filename itself?

> Are there any better alternatives?
>   Are there any overlooked cases which the function doesn't cover?

Maybe, depending on your intended use case.

> Are there server settings in which a script may not be able to read itself
>
> ```
> is_readable(__FILE__)===false
> ```

Code run in the PHP interactive shell is one case where `is_readable(__FILE__)===false`.

---

Some miscellaneous notes:

- Using `#` for comments is unusual; you usually only see `#` used in the shebang line.
- Reusing the `$file` variable for both a file name and an array of lines from the file is confusing.
- Stripping comments does not seem necessary given your stated goal (acting like JavaScript's `Function.prototype.toString`).

---

Without knowing more about your intended use case, I'd suggest something much simpler, along the lines of:

```
function fn_to_string($fn) {
    $r = new ReflectionFunction($fn);
    $file = $r->getFileName();
    if (!is_readable($file)) {
        return '';
    }
    $lines = file($file);
    $start = $r->getStartLine() - 1;
    $length = $r->getEndLine() - $start;

    return implode('', array_slice($lines, $start, $length));
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you very much for taking your time on this. The intended goal here is to convert code from PHP into other languages, like JS. Will update the question.